# CAPTCHA has no submit button

Tags: bug, captcha

I took a long time to compose my post, and was prompted by a house-number captcha. Easy. Then I was re-prompted to copy&paste some code into a text box ... but there's no way to submit that form!

I click in the first text box (anywhere in the code), then do Ctrl+C. Then I click in the second text box, then do Ctrl-V. `Enter` simply inserts a newline, as expected = no submit. Ctrl+Enter does nothing.

**How do I get past this?** (I am not a robot.)

When I use the `Tab` key to find any clickable hyperlinks or buttons, all I get is the orange "CAPTCHA" link to the right.

Upon retrying in a new browser window, I notice that the first captcha includes a suspiciously empty text box underneath the "Verify" button. It looks like the "Paste it here" text box in the screenshot, but without any label above it. "Privacy - Terms" appears below it.

- Ubuntu 14.10
- Chromium 40.0.2214.111

[image]

Comment: Well that's really odd. Have you tried pressing enter? I would hazard a guess that the button only shows if you pasted it properly, but I'm sure you did so..

Comment: I updated my post, @Seth. I'm also heading to bed now, so this meta topic (and my main topic) will have to wait 8 hours. See you later :-)